# HttpClient on Android using Wifi causes delay (on initial request)

Tags: android, https, wifi, httpclient, delay

I'm having this wierd problem with HttpClient on Android. If I try to connect to a https url using WiFi I'm having a delay before the acctual request is sent. If I send the request over 3G the delay does not exist.

It does however, only occur on Android 2.2 and 2.3, If i run it on for example 2.1-update1 it works fine on wifi as well.

However, when sending requests right after the initial request - it works properly on Wifi as well - but only for a while. Then it goes back to taking 10 seconds for one, and then properly again for a while...

When running on 2.3:
11285 ms

And on 1.6:
617 ms

The code I'm using to try and solve this problem is this
[HttpManager](https://github.com/johannilsson/sthlmtraveling/blob/master/src/com/markupartist/sthlmtraveling/utils/HttpManager.java) and:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Button button;
TextView text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doRequest();
        }

    });
}

private void doRequest() {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://url_goes_here/");

    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        httpResponse = HttpManager.execute(httpget);
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        String response = convertStreamToString(entity.getContent());
        Log.i("Test", response);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText((String) "Time: " + (after-before) + "\n" + response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Simplified code a bit
    }
}

protected static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The line where the delay occurs is HttpManager.execute(httpget); which also is the line I calculate the ms on.

Has anyone ever been facing this problem? I find this delay very annoying, and so will my users. Emulators behave the same way as an Xperia Mini Pro running 2.1-update1 where it works properly over Wifi, and a HTC Desire running CyanogenMod 7 (2.3) where it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the ssl stack included with android.  I struggled with this as well.  Go to the apache home, and get the org.apache.http java package (I used v4.1).  Include that in your application and use the HttpClient from it directly, instead of using the HttpClient built into Android, and your SSL Handshake delay problem will be resolved.

Comment: This does not seem to work, unfortunately. Also, why would it work over 3G and not wifi if this would be the problem? :/

Comment: Hmm... What I saw was that on wifi, the SSL Handshake delay was much more obvious simply due to the speed of the connection, whereas other latency issues on 3G masked the time.  I saw some very strange and inconsistent behaviors on wifi vs. 3G, on multiple devices.   Noteably, we had no problems at all on os 1.6 on the Backflip, just as you described.

From your descirption of 1st-time problems, you must be reusing your HttpClient, which is good, but it again points to SSL handshake being the time-sink, as that does not need to be performed on each request.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Just to make sure I add httpclient.4.1.1.jar, httpcore-4.1.jar and httpmime-4.1.1.jar correctly... The only thing I need to do is add them to build path, right?

Comment: Wierd thing is, if I try api.myphotodiary.com over wifi, I get 10 second delays on first request, however if I try some graph.facebook.com url I get 500ms at tops on all requests. Both over SSL :/
This problem is really starting to confuse me...

Comment: You could include the jar, but you may want to get the source, so you only need to include the specific classes, to keep app size down.  Then make sure you import the org.apache.http.v4_1.client.HttpClient and related classes directly, so the app won't use the built-in.
I hope this helps for you!

Comment: Seems you're right. If I do a sample application in Java and run it on my Laptop using latest HttpClient 4.1.1 I get about 500 ms trying to connect to the same URL as the Android application does in 10000 ms.

Adding the jars doesn't work, as it seems to use the old HttpClient anyway. Therefore I'm going to have to add the specific classes myself.. Which seems to be veeery many, and then put them in another package... I'll report back if it works though! If it does, you're damn good.

Comment: I can confirm that this works - using HttpClient 4.1.1 resolves this problem. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I know it's a pain :)  This took us a couple weeks to diagnose and fix.  The reason it keeps using the original HttpClient is the class loading order.  It's loading the default HttpClient before the 4.1.1 version you are including.  I had forgotten, what we did was changed the package name of the new HttpClient.  That way we could import the new HttpClient with a different package name, and there would no longer be a class conflict.

Comment: Could someone explain how to force use third-party apache downloaded from apache website, added to project and dependencies. It seems I still use built-in Android HttpClient, however, new apache.jar already added. How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Disable DNS Relay on your router! It just worked for me!

Also, no version of httpclient or httpcore changed it for me.